# Simple EditText currency formatter

Tags: android, currency

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Better way to Format Currency Input editText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107901/better-way-to-format-currency-input-edittext)

The problem is simple and basic... but I can't find a decent way of handling it.
I have some fields with money values and I need to have both the currency symbol and the decimal value. Here is what I am talking about:

[image]

The user will input the value:  1 and then . and then 8 and then 0. The EUR symbol I want it to be visible all time.

What's the best way of achieving  this ?

Comment: As the answers say, you can probably accomplish this with a `TextWatcher`, but wouldn't it be easier to just move the symbol to the right of the `EditText` (outside it).

Comment: @Alin: So is it necessary for it to constantly show the Euro symbol? Personally, I'd just format after the user enters the amount (i.e. they enter 1.8, exit the EditText, it shows €1.80)

Comment: ... and sometimes the currency sign is left of the number (dollars, pound), sometimes right of the number (Euro)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to use a textwatcher :D

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

[Better way to Format Currency Input editText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107901/better-way-to-format-currency-input-edittext)

With this u can format the incoming String before its display,
so u can easily append a "€" and other stuff

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by using a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html). Look at this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107901/better-way-to-format-currency-input-edittext) which is quite similar to yours.