# Text Selection in TextView

Tags: android, textview, android-actionmode

I know there is an attribute `android:textIsSelectable="true"` which enables text selection in a `TextView`  by a  long click on text and after that it shows an `ActionMode` for manipulating text.My question is how can I disable the default `ActionMode`? I tried to disable it by writing a custom ActionMode and returning `false` in it's `onCreateActionMode` method:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }
```

and passed it to the:

```
TextView.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(customActionMode);
```

It ruined text selection and disabled Start-End pointers.
I want to disable `ActionMode` to write my own `PopupWindow` after selecting text.
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Your solution is here http://stackoverflow.com/a/17137052/1915697..

Comment: Thx but it already implemented in the Textview and I want to use the default one not some custom text selection with so many bugs :) just wanna know how to disable action mode.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12982251/1915697 it

Comment: @YogeshTatwal: thank you but it is for EditText , I'm seeking TextView dude :)