# android EditText format as i type

Tags: android, onchange

I have this problem, how can I format the display on edittext as i type on it? for example if i type 5 it will format for desired currency. i can format the text in edittext without problem on onFocusChangeListener but the client needs onchange.

here are some code:

```
   <code>
    inputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_compare_rate_saving);
    inputText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2)               {
            //System.out.println("beforeTextChanged::: => "+charSequence);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            //System.out.println("onTextChanged::: => "+charSequence);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            if(!editable.toString().isEmpty()){
                String amount = LO.removeSeparators(editable.toString(), getLocaleFormat());
                String newFormat = LO.compareRatesFormatting(Double.valueOf(amount),getLocaleFormat());
                System.out.println("afterTextChanged::: => "+newFormat);
                inputText.setText(newFormat);
            }
            //System.out.println("afterTextChanged::: => "+editable.toString());
        }
    });

   </code>
```

im having a stackoverflow error

```
  <code>
    08-01 22:37:32.724: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1566): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at android.view.View.addFocusables(View.java:4311)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:731)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:731)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:731)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:731)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:731)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:731)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:731)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:731)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:731)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:712)
    at android.view.View.getFocusables(View.java:4269)
    at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocus(FocusFinder.java:114)
    at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocus(FocusFinder.java:98)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:570)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:572)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:572)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:572)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:572)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:572)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:572)
    at android.view.View.focusSearch(View.java:4192)
    at android.widget.TextView.onCreateInputConnection(TextView.java:4936)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.startInputInner(InputMethodManager.java:964)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.restartInput(InputMethodManager.java:919)

    </code>
```

Any idea?
cheers.
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

To shed a little more light on the situation, the documentation for [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) explicitly states that you should take care when changing text in afterTextChanged:

> public abstract void afterTextChanged (Editable s)
>
> This method is called to notify you that, somewhere
>   within s, the text has been changed. It is legitimate to make further
>   changes to s from this callback, but **be careful not to get yourself
>   into an infinite loop, because any changes you make will cause this
>   method to be called again recursively.** (You are not told where the
>   change took place because other afterTextChanged() methods may already
>   have made other changes and invalidated the offsets. But if you need
>   to know here, you can use setSpan(Object, int, int, int) in
>   onTextChanged(CharSequence, int, int, int) to mark your place and then
>   look up from here where the span ended up.

Comment: thanks for reply...i find this http://android-sdk.appspot.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.html which a utility to watch a textview upon change on of text. is it possible to do similar to this on edittext itself?  Thanks

Comment: i find this post helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107901/better-way-to-format-currency-input-edittext

Answer (score 0):

You're in an infinite loop and that's why you get the stackoverflow. Everytime the text changes, your afterTextChanged gets called, which changes the text and causes it to be called again