# How to format currency input

Tags: java, android

My question is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107901/better-way-to-format-currency-input-edittext). I am also looking for the same type of formatting but in reverse order.

Like if I press one it should print 1.00, then I press 2 and it will be 12.00. Then I press 3 it will be 123.00.

If I press (.) dot then it will be 123.00 only. And if now I press 9 then it will be 123.90, and if I then press 6 it will be 123.96 and will be till 2 decimal places only. Values after decimal will not increase after 2 and length of the value before the decimal point is unlimited. Pressing backspace deletes the last entered number.

Comment: What have you tried ? Where do you struggle? Give some code so people can help you.

Comment: hi i tried some code can you look on this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675156/format-price-in-0-00-format-in-android-using-edittext

Answer (score 1):

You can use two int variables

- one should store values before decimal
- second should store values after decimal, also make sure value is not greater than 99 here.

after the input is complete join the two int variables into a string with a decimal place.

then parse it into a float variable.

Comment: thank you i appreciate your answer , I will try this. Could you tell little about how to implement this on android edittext

Comment: are u trying to make a calculator ?