# Format Price in 0.00 format in android using edittext

Tags: java, android

I am trying to mask a price value so that it is always in `0.00` format. Here is my code

```
float temp = 0;

DecimalFormat mDecimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("###.00");

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    if(s.toString()!=null)
    {

        mMasEditText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
        temp = Float.parseFloat(s.toString());
        mMasEditText.setText(""+mDecimalFormat.format(addNumber(temp)));
        mMasEditText.setSelection(start+1);
        mMasEditText.addTextChangedListener(this);

    }
}

public float addNumber(float numTemp){
    float result=0.00f;
    result = numTemp + result;
    return result;
}
```

But when I am pressing decimal, I want the cursor to go to one more step. But I am not able to get the dot callback. Also when I am pressing the back button, to remove digits, I get an index out of bound exception. Can anyone tell me how to get the back button and dot button callback before onTextChanged listener?

Comment: Maybe you should add the trace of the index out of bound exception

Answer (score 0):

use `String.format`

```
  String.format("$%.2f", result);
```

or

```
   Strint text = String.format("$%.2f", addNumber(temp));
   mMasEditText.setText(text)
```

Comment: illegalformatconversionexception %f cant format java.lang.string.arguments

Comment: Strint text = String.format("$%.2f", addNumber(temp)); I forget to remove mDecimal.format

Comment: I think you did not tested the code for android edittext , your code just add an $ before price and when try to add other digit itsays invalid float error ($1.00). when i remove $ from string.format  then again pressing dot, says invalid float 144..00 .

Comment: My problem will be solved when on pressing dot my selector goes one more position in edit text , do you have any idea how to get the dot event on edit text

Answer (score 0):

Recommended way of formatting currency and prices:

```
    Locale loc = Locale.getDefault();
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(loc);
    nf.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance(loc));
    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);

    System.out.println(nf.format(23.5634));
    System.out.println(nf.format(0.5));
```

Comment: I am not concerned with the $ sign , I only need the formatting of 0.00 . suppose when i press 1  it will be  1.00  and agina i press 2 it will be 12.00 the i press . (dot ) it will be 12.00 now i press 5 it will be 12.50 and i press 8 it will be 12.58 , and so on .

Comment: And all this need to be done for android edittext  the above code works fine for that butbut not able to get the dot event callback for the edittext

Comment: @Suri This is just the method of getting well formated price according to one's country and locale. Also format contents of `EditText` when user has completed editing and it looses focus . Messing with user editing in real time is not a good idea.