# android onkeyDown not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

Hi i am trying to get call back of button pressed (.) and (delete)/(<==)  in onkeydown in activity. 
I used the following methods

```
        @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Log.d(""+keyCode, ""+event);
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}



         mMasEditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {           
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            Log.d("pressed", "Pressed");
            if (event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                //do something here
                mMasEditText.setText("0.00");
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Is callback will come on both the overridden methods ? why call back is not coming in onkeydown and why i am not able to get deleted call back using onkeylistner in edittext

Comment: what's exactly your problem?

Comment: i am not getting call back in onkeydown , also  i am trying to get the call back when i press (.) button in android keyboard and back button(delete) . I am using inputtype numberdecimal

Comment: all this i am doing to achieve the solution to this problem  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675156/format-price-in-0-00-format-in-android-using-edittext