# How to use getText while dropping certain characters

Tags: java, android, gettext, decimalformat

Needing some simple help here. Basically, I've got this line:

```
String stringA = numA.getText().toString();
```

However, the `numA` editText that this is using also has a `DecimalFormat` method called on it before it gets to this point, which makes the out put look like: `$###,###,###.00`. So, when I go to call `getText` on `numA`, it crashes.  I'm assuming this is because of the $ sign or commas.  How would I change this code so that `getText` only catches the numbers and not the $ sign or commas?

Comment: Please post the stack trace of the Exception you are getting, along with the code generating it (marking the line which throws the exception).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
String stringA = numA.getText().toString().replace("$", "").replace(",", "");
```

Comment: Why didn't I think of `replace`? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

**when I go to call getText on numA, it crashes**

The only possible thing is your `EditText numA` is `NULL`.

Update:

Look at [Better way to Format Currency Input editText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107901/better-way-to-format-currency-input-edittext)

Comment: No, it isn't because it is `NULL`.  The method actually checks for it using an `if` clause before anything happens to it.  The method was actually working before I set the DecimalFormat as I stated.

Comment: `toString()` return any class declaration which the method returns. So only one possibilities is your `getText()` rerun `NULL`. Check for actual exception post stack trace with question.

Comment: This is the actual exception upon last run:
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "$4,700.15"

Comment: Yupp.. As I told you .. Now put complete stack trace with code in your question.