# Android EditText format with leading zero

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, format

I'm fairly new in the android game, and I'm trying to build a CountDown Timer similar to the android timer.

Here is my code so far, followed by some questions I have

```
public class TimeTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    private final int TEXT_HOUR = 0;
    private final int TEXT_MINUTE = 1;
    private final int TEXT_SECOND = 2;

    private EditText Hours;
    private EditText Minutes;
    private EditText Seconds;
    private int Type;

    public TimeTextWatcher(EditText h, EditText m, EditText s, int type){
        Hours = h;
        Minutes = m;
        Seconds = s;
        Type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        Hours.removeTextChangedListener(this);
        Hours.setText(String.format("%02d", Integer.parseInt(s.toString())));
        Hours.setSelection(Hours.getText().length());
        Hours.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        int curr_value;
        if (s.toString().equals(""))
            curr_value = -1;
        else
            curr_value = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());

        switch(Type){
            case TEXT_HOUR:
                if (curr_value > 9)
                    Minutes.requestFocus();
                break;
            case TEXT_MINUTE:
                if (curr_value > 59)
                    s.replace(0, 2, Integer.toString(59));

                if (curr_value > 9)
                    Seconds.requestFocus();
                break;
            case TEXT_SECOND:
                if (curr_value > 59)
                    s.replace(0, 2, Integer.toString(59));
                break;
            default:
                Log.d("TimeTextWatcher", "Error in switch case");
        }
    }
}
```

As I said, I'm trying to make it behave similarly to the android built in CountDown timer.
some information:

- each editText in MainActivity has it's own `addTextChangedListener` with this class.
- each editText is limited to 2 chars.
- when I enter number bigger than 9, it changes focus to the next editText

My goals:

1. when typing the number '23', I want that first it will show '02' (after pressing '2') with leading zero, and then after pressing '3' - the whole number.
2. focus on the next editText regarding the input number, but after pressing on two digits.

I've tried using `new DecimalFormat("00")` or `setText(String.format("%02d", Integer.parseInt(s.toString())))`, but it gets stuck after pressing one digit.

Hope I was clear enough..
Thanks!

Comment: My suggestion is to divide and conquer. Are you sure the plain setText (say, passing a constant) would work as expected? Are you sure String.format("%02d", Integer.parseInt(s.toString())) alone is working as expected? If the input comes from a EditText, you should verify it can be parsed as int before actually doing it..Even if you specified "number" input type for that EditText

Comment: Why do you set a new value to Hours EditText only, regardless of Type variable (minutes, seconds)?

Comment: @Shine, it works. for example if I press key '2', the editText is changed to '02', but nothing happens if I press any other key. It still stays '02'.
Took the idea from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107901/better-way-to-format-currency-input-edittext
He says it works for him, but didn't for me for some reason

Comment: @JonTom, it's just a sketch for testing it. tried to see if it works on one of them.