# EditText decimal mask for android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, masking

I'm working in an Android application and i want to create a decimal mask for editText in android. I want a mask like a maskMoney jQuery plugin. But in some cases my number will have 2 decimal places, 3 decimal places or will be a integer. I want do something like this:

- When the EditText is created, come with a default value: 00.01
- If user press the number 2, the result should be: 00.12
- If user press the number 3, the result should be: 01.23
- If user press the number 4, the result should be: 12.34
- If user press the number 5, the result should be: 123.45
- If user press the number 6, the result should be: 1,234.56

What's the best way to do that?

Comment: Have you tried using `NumberFormat`?

Comment: See the discussions here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107901/better-way-to-format-currency-input-edittext

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I resolved with this:

```
public static TextWatcher amount(final EditText editText, final String metric) {
    return new TextWatcher() {
        String current = "";

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (!s.toString().equals(current)) {
                editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);

                String cleanString = s.toString();

                if (count != 0) {
                    String substr = cleanString.substring(cleanString.length() - 2);

                    if (substr.contains(".") || substr.contains(",")) {
                        cleanString += "0";
                    }
                }

                cleanString = cleanString.replaceAll("[,.]", "");

                double parsed = Double.parseDouble(cleanString);
                DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
                String formatted = df.format((parsed / 100));

                current = formatted;
                editText.setText(formatted);
                editText.setSelection(formatted.length());

                editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
            }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    };
}
```