# Currency input with 2 decimal format

Tags: android, android-edittext, currency

I need to format input currency with 2 decimal format 
example when user enter 2 it looks $2.00 then when when user enter 2 it convert to $22.00 ... etc

I approach to something similar , when user enter 2 it convert to $0.02 next 2 will be like this $0.22

any one can help me thank you

```
public class MoneyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    private final WeakReference<EditText> editTextWeakReference;

    public MoneyTextWatcher(EditText mEditText) {
        editTextWeakReference = new WeakReference<EditText>(mEditText);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

       EditText editTex = editTextWeakReference.get();
        if(!s.toString().equals(editTex.getText())) {
            editTex.removeTextChangedListener(this);
            String cleanString = s.toString().replaceAll("[$,.]", "");
            double parsed = Double.parseDouble(cleanString.replaceAll("[^\\d]", ""));
            String formatted = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format((parsed / 100));
            editTex.setText(formatted);
            editTex.setSelection(formatted.length());

            editTex.addTextChangedListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }


    }
}
```

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107901/better-way-to-format-currency-input-edittext yet?

Comment: What about floating numbers? Do you want to allow user to enter something like $22.51, or you work with integers only?

Comment: integers only , my code work nice with float number

Comment: There's a standardised way to work with DOM [Document Object Model] and SAX [Simple API for XML] in Java that's detailed in the articles below. Sorry for the lack of detail, but I don't want to spend a huge amount of time replicating someone else's work http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076886/java-se/xml-apis-for-databases.html https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/ Hope this is useful

Comment: same is the question i have asked please see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59387099/decimal-input-edittext-in-java/59540365#59540365)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think you can try the following:

Layout:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        />
```

Activity:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.addTextChangedListener(new NumberTextWatcher(editText, "#,###"));
```

with text watcher as the following:

```
public class NumberTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    private final DecimalFormat df;
    private final DecimalFormat dfnd;
    private final EditText et;
    private boolean hasFractionalPart;
    private int trailingZeroCount;

    public NumberTextWatcher(EditText editText, String pattern) {
        df = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
        df.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(true);
        dfnd = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");
        this.et = editText;
        hasFractionalPart = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        et.removeTextChangedListener(this);

        if (s != null && !s.toString().isEmpty()) {
            try {
                int inilen, endlen;
                inilen = et.getText().length();
                String v = s.toString().replace(String.valueOf(df.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getGroupingSeparator()), "").replace("$","");
                Number n = df.parse(v);
                int cp = et.getSelectionStart();
                if (hasFractionalPart) {
                    StringBuilder trailingZeros = new StringBuilder();
                    while (trailingZeroCount-- > 0)
                        trailingZeros.append('0');
                    et.setText(df.format(n) + trailingZeros.toString());
                } else {
                    et.setText(dfnd.format(n));
                }
                et.setText("$".concat(et.getText().toString()));
                endlen = et.getText().length();
                int sel = (cp + (endlen - inilen));
                if (sel > 0 && sel < et.getText().length()) {
                    et.setSelection(sel);
                } else if (trailingZeroCount > -1) {
                    et.setSelection(et.getText().length() - 3);
                } else {
                    et.setSelection(et.getText().length());
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException | ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        et.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        int index = s.toString().indexOf(String.valueOf(df.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator()));
        trailingZeroCount = 0;
        if (index > -1) {
            for (index++; index < s.length(); index++) {
                if (s.charAt(index) == '0')
                    trailingZeroCount++;
                else {
                    trailingZeroCount = 0;
                }
            }
            hasFractionalPart = true;
        } else {
            hasFractionalPart = false;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: How to convert such that user can enter the fractional part as well.?
E.g. - User enters 2435.89 .

Comment: Fractional part after the decimal point doesn't seem to accept non-zero inputs.

Answer (score 4):

Keep the number entered by the user stored apart, since if you use your edittext.text you will have more problems.

Then use [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) to format it like you need.

For the first, maybe its a good way to restore the original input to the edittext as soon as the users begins editing, this way you can avoid problems with the editing.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

HI below code will convert every number to two decimal.
the value should be number, characters and special characters can cause numberformat exception. please handle that as you needed. Thanks

```
    public static String formatDecimal(String value) {
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###,##0.00");
    return df.format(Double.valueOf(value));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I lost incredible ten hours searching or trying codes for this. 
So I gave up and built this code for myself. Its not revised yet but it works and I´ve came here to help others that went crazy with this like me.

The code basically is a function that will place a textWatcher and adjust the coma to the right place. 
This code is for Kotlin.

First, create this function:

```
fun CurrencyWatcher( editText:EditText) {

    editText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        //this will prevent the loop
        var changed: Boolean = false

        override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
            changed = false

        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {

            editText.setSelection(p0.toString().length)
        }

        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
            if (!changed) {
                changed = true

                var str: String = p0.toString().replace(",", "").trim()
                var element0: String = str.elementAt(0).toString()
                var element1: String = "x"
                var element2: String = "x"
                var element3: String = "x"
                var element4: String = "x"
                var element5: String = "x"
                var element6: String = "x"

                //this variables will store each elements of the initials data for the case we need to move this numbers like: 0,01 to 0,11 or 0,11 to 0,01
                if (str.length >= 2) {
                    element1 = str.elementAt(1).toString()
                }
                if (str.length >= 3) {
                    element2 = str.elementAt(2).toString()
                }

                editText.removeTextChangedListener(this)


                //this first block of code will take care of the case
                //where the number starts with 0 and needs to adjusta the 0 and the "," place
                if (str.length == 1) {
                    str = "0,0" + str
                    editText.setText(str)

                } else if (str.length <= 3 && str == "00") {

                    str = "0,00"
                    editText.setText(str)
                    editText.setSelection(str.length)
                } else if (element0 == "0" && element1 == "0" && element2 == "0") {
                    str = str.replace("000", "")
                    str = "0,0" + str
                    editText.setText(str)
                } else if (element0 == "0" && element1 == "0" && element2 != "0") {
                    str = str.replace("00", "")
                    str = "0," + str
                    editText.setText(str)
                } else {

                    //This block of code works with the cases that we need to move the "," only because the value is bigger
                    //lets get the others elements
                    if (str.length >= 4) {
                        element3 = str.elementAt(3).toString()
                    }
                    if (str.length >= 5) {
                        element4 = str.elementAt(4).toString()
                    }
                    if (str.length >= 6) {
                        element5 = str.elementAt(5).toString()
                    }
                    if (str.length == 7) {
                        element6 = str.elementAt(6).toString()
                    }


                    if (str.length >= 4 && element0 != "0") {

                        val sb: StringBuilder = StringBuilder(str)
                        //set the coma in right place
                        sb.insert(str.length - 2, ",")
                        str = sb.toString()
                    }

                    //change the 0,11 to 1,11
                    if (str.length == 4 && element0 == "0") {

                        val sb: StringBuilder = StringBuilder(str)
                        //takes the initial 0 out
                        sb.deleteCharAt(0);
                        str = sb.toString()

                        val sb2: StringBuilder = StringBuilder(str)
                        sb2.insert(str.length - 2, ",")
                        str = sb2.toString()
                    }

                    //this will came up when its like 11,11 and the user delete one, so it will be now 1,11
                    if (str.length == 3 && element0 != "0") {
                        val sb: StringBuilder = StringBuilder(str)
                        sb.insert(str.length - 2, ",")
                        str = sb.toString()
                    }

                    //came up when its like 0,11 and the user delete one, output will be 0,01
                    if (str.length == 2 && element0 == "0") {
                        val sb: StringBuilder = StringBuilder(str)
                        //takes 0 out
                        sb.deleteCharAt(0);
                        str = sb.toString()

                        str = "0,0" + str

                    }

                    //came up when its 1,11 and the user delete, output will be 0,11
                    if (str.length == 2 && element0 != "0") {
                        val sb: StringBuilder = StringBuilder(str)
                        //retira o 0 da frente
                        sb.insert(0, "0,")
                        str = sb.toString()

                    }


                    editText.setText(str)
                }

                //places the selector at the end to increment the number
                editText.setSelection(str.length)
                editText.addTextChangedListener(this)
            }

        }
    })
}
```

And then you call this function this way

```
val etVal:EditText = findViewById(R.id.etValue)

CurrencyWatcher(etVal)
```

Comment: this is unusable - after every digit selection jumps to the end and stops responding - you have to manually put selection for every digit. backspace works well tho