# Decimal input edittext in java

Tags: java, android, decimal, currency-formatting

I want to have an edit text with some value like 0.00 and cursor must be on the left side. when user press 1 it should be 1.00, when user presses 2 it should be 12.00, when user press "." cursor should move to the other side of decimal. After shifting to the other side of decimal when user press 3 it should be 12.30 and on pressing 4 it should be 12.34. Similarly on backpress it should be 12.30 -> 12.00 -> 1.00 -> 0.00.[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qocy1.gif)

```
 import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class AmountTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    private EditText editText;
    private int num_npt;
    private String previous;
    private boolean isBackSpacePressed;

    public AmountTextWatcher(EditText editText, int num_npt) {
        this.editText = editText;
        this.num_npt = num_npt;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        /*if (StorageUtils.INTERNAL_TRANSFER_AMOUNT != 0.00)
            previous = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%.2f", StorageUtils.INTERNAL_TRANSFER_AMOUNT);
        else*/
        if (after < count) {
            isBackSpacePressed = true;
        } else {
            isBackSpacePressed = false;
        }
        previous = editText.getText().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);


        if (isBackSpacePressed) {
            String old_val = previous;

            int point = old_val.indexOf(".");
            if (point == -1) point = old_val.length();

            int selectionStart = editText.getSelectionStart() + 1;
            int selectionEnd = editText.getSelectionEnd();

            String new_val = "";
            if (selectionStart < selectionEnd) {
                if (selectionEnd <= point) {
                    new_val = old_val.substring(0, selectionStart) + old_val.substring(selectionEnd);
                } else if (selectionStart > point) {
                    new_val = old_val.substring(0, selectionStart) + "0" + old_val.substring(selectionEnd);
                    if (selectionEnd - selectionStart == num_npt) new_val += "0";
                } else if (selectionStart <= point && selectionEnd > point) {
                    new_val = old_val.substring(0, selectionStart) + ".";
                    for (int z = 0; z < selectionEnd - point - 1; z++) new_val += "0";
                    new_val += old_val.substring(selectionEnd);
                }

                if (new_val.indexOf(".") == 0) new_val = "0" + new_val;

            } else if (selectionStart == 1 && point == 1) {
                new_val = "0" + old_val.substring(1);
                selectionStart = 0;
            } else if (selectionStart > 0 && selectionStart <= point) {
                new_val = old_val.substring(0, selectionStart - 1) + old_val.substring(selectionStart);
                selectionStart--;
            } else if (selectionStart == point + 1) {
                new_val = old_val;
                selectionStart = point;
            } else if (selectionStart > point + 1) {
                new_val = old_val.substring(0, selectionStart - 1) + old_val.substring(selectionStart) + "0";
                selectionStart--;
            } else {
                new_val = old_val;
            }

            if (new_val.equals("")) new_val = "0";
            editText.setText(new_val);
            editText.setSelection(selectionStart);
            editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
        } else {

            int point = previous.indexOf(".");
            if (point == -1) point = previous.length();

            int selectionStart = editText.getSelectionStart() - 1;
            int selectionEnd = editText.getSelectionEnd() - 1;

            String c = s.subSequence(start, start + count).toString();
            if (c.equals("-") || c.equals(" ")) {
                editText.setText(previous);
                editText.setSelection(selectionStart);
                editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
                return;
            }
            String new_val = "";

            if (selectionStart > -1 && selectionStart < editText.getText().length() - 1) {
                if (c != null && c.length() > 0) {
                    if (c.equals(",")) c = ".";
                    if (Character.isDigit(c.charAt(0)) || c.equals(".")) {
                        if (selectionStart < selectionEnd) {
                            if (selectionEnd <= point) {
                                new_val = previous.substring(0, selectionStart) + c + previous.substring(selectionEnd);
                            } else if (selectionStart > point) {
                                new_val = previous.substring(0, selectionStart) + c + previous.substring(selectionEnd);
                                for (int x = 0; x < selectionEnd - selectionStart - 1; x++)
                                    new_val += "0";
                            } else if (selectionStart <= point && selectionEnd > point && !c.equals(".")) {
                                new_val = previous.substring(0, selectionStart) + c + ".";
                                for (int y = 0; y < selectionEnd - point - 1; y++)
                                    new_val += "0";
                                new_val += previous.substring(selectionEnd);
                            }
                        } else if ((num_npt == 0 && previous.equals("0")) || (previous.substring(0, 2).equals("0.") && selectionStart == 0)) {
                            if (c.equals(".")) {
                                new_val = previous;
                                editText.setSelection(0);
                            } else
                                new_val = c + previous.substring(1);
                        } else if (selectionStart > point && selectionStart <= point + num_npt) {
                            if (c.equals(".")) {
                                if (editText.getSelectionStart() > previous.indexOf("."))
                                    new_val = previous.substring(0, selectionStart) + previous.substring(selectionStart);
                                else
                                    new_val = previous.substring(0, selectionStart - 1) + c + previous.substring(selectionStart);
                                editText.setSelection(selectionStart - 1);
                            } else
                                new_val = previous.substring(0, selectionStart) + c + previous.substring(selectionStart + 1);
                        }
                        // this is the code where our edittext lags :(
                        else {
                            if (c.equals("."))
                                if (editText.getSelectionStart() - 1 == 0) {
                                    if (c.equals("."))
                                        new_val = previous.substring(0, 1) + previous.substring(selectionEnd + 1);
                                    else
                                        new_val = previous.substring(0, 1) + c + previous.substring(selectionEnd + 2);
                                } else {
                                    if (selectionStart > 0 && selectionStart < previous.indexOf("."))
                                        new_val = previous.substring(0, selectionStart + 1) + previous.substring(selectionEnd + 1);
                                    else
                                        new_val = previous.substring(0, selectionStart) + c + previous.substring(selectionEnd + 1);
                                }
                            else
                                new_val = previous.substring(0, selectionStart) + c + previous.substring(selectionEnd);
                            if (new_val.substring(new_val.length() - 1).equals("."))
                                new_val = new_val.substring(0, new_val.length() - 1);
                        }
                        // *********//

                        if (new_val.substring(0, 1).equals("0") && !new_val.substring(0, 2).equals("0.")) {
                            new_val = new_val.substring(1);
                            selectionStart--;
                        }

                        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]{0," + num_npt + "})?$");
                        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(new_val);
                        boolean doNothing = false;
                        if (matcher.matches()) {
                            editText.setText(new_val);
                            if (!c.equals("."))
                                selectionStart++;
                            else if (c.equals(".") && selectionStart == previous.indexOf("."))
                                selectionStart++;
                            editText.setSelection(selectionStart);
                        } else if (c.equals(".")) {
                            selectionStart++;
                            editText.setSelection(selectionStart);
                        }
                        editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
                    }
                } else {
                    editText.setText(previous);
                    editText.setSelection(selectionStart);
                    editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
                }
            } else {
                int length = editText.getText().length();
                if (selectionStart < 0)
                    selectionStart = 0;
                else if (selectionStart > length || selectionEnd < length)
                    selectionStart = length - 1;
                editText.setText(previous);
                editText.setSelection(selectionStart);
                editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
}
```

Comment: This code work as you want.. What is the difficulty you are facing?

Comment: this is not good solution. it lags while writing. miss many numbers, user experience is very bad

Comment: @Md have you tried this code ?

Comment: is there anyone who have found some optimized answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.format("%.2f", d)` inside your `onTextChanged` to format

**Update 1:**

```
etText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new DecimalDigitsInputFilter(5, 2)});
```

```
class DecimalDigitsInputFilter implements InputFilter {
   private Pattern mPattern;
   DecimalDigitsInputFilter(int digitsBeforeZero, int digitsAfterZero) {
      mPattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{0," + (digitsBeforeZero - 1) + "}+((\\.[0-9]{0," + (digitsAfterZero - 1) + "})?)||(\\.)?");
   }
   @Override
   public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
      Matcher matcher = mPattern.matcher(dest);
      if (!matcher.matches())
      return "";
      return null;
   }
}
```

Comment: i have tried this it rounds off the double value. What do i want is to write numbers on both sides of decimal point

Comment: thanku for the answer @Niraj. It only limits digits before and after the decimal point, but it does not handle the backpress case and shifting cases on decimal point click, it just limits the number of digits before and after decimal

Comment: I think my issue can only be solved through textwatcher. there is no other solution

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **DecimalFormat** Class in Java. It may help you in a better way.

```
String pattern = "##.##";
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
String output = decimalFormat.format( YOUR NUMBER HERE );
```

Comment: avoid using textwatcher if you are using DecimalFormat

Comment: thanku @arnab can you please send me the code snippet so, that i can try. I have tried all the things available on the internet but unable to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

xml

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_des_input"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="0.00"
    android:digits=".0123456789"/>
```

Set TextWacher

```
EditText et_des_input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_des_input);
et_des_input.addTextChangedListener(new AmountTextWatcher(et_des_input, 2));
```

TextWacher class is same as you post. It is working as you ask for.

[See the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5Bow.gif)

Comment: i know this solution works but problem is that it lags when you test it on samsung s7. It does not write as other edittext does. Is there any better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have made this solution for two decimal places. Please check it guys. this works for two decimal places.

public class TxLabzTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

```
EditText editText;
String tempText = "";
StringBuilder stringBuilder;
Context ctx;
boolean isBackSpacePressed = false;
int digitsAfteZero;
int count;
boolean isFirstDigitBeforeDecimalZero = true;


public TxLabzTextWatcher(Context context, EditText editText, int digitsAfterZero) {

    this.editText = editText;
    tempText = editText.getText().toString();
    stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    this.ctx = context;
    this.digitsAfteZero = digitsAfterZero;
    count = 0;

}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    if (after < count) {
        isBackSpacePressed = true;
    } else {
        isBackSpacePressed = false;
    }

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);

    if (stringBuilder.toString().isEmpty()) {
        stringBuilder.append("0.00");
    }

    if (!isBackSpacePressed) {
        editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
        stringBuilder.setLength(0);
        stringBuilder.append(s);
        char ch = s.charAt(start + before);

        if (!isClickDot(ch)) {
            if (stringBuilder.length() > 0 && stringBuilder.indexOf(".") - 1 == editText.getSelectionStart() && stringBuilder.charAt(stringBuilder.indexOf(".") - 1) == '0' && ch != '0' && isFirstDigitBeforeDecimalZero) {
                stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(stringBuilder.indexOf(".") - 1);
                editText.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
                editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length() - 3);
                isFirstDigitBeforeDecimalZero = false;
            } else if (ch == '0' && stringBuilder.indexOf(".") - 1 == editText.getSelectionStart()) {
                stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(stringBuilder.indexOf(".") - 1);
                editText.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
                editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length() - 3);
                isFirstDigitBeforeDecimalZero = false;
            }
        }


        // if i press dot then move to the other side of
        if (isClickDot(ch) && StringUtils.countMatches(stringBuilder.toString(), ".") >= 1) {
            stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(s.toString().indexOf('.'));
            editText.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
            editText.setSelection(s.toString().indexOf('.') + 1);
        }

        // replace first digit after decimal
        if (stringBuilder.indexOf(".") + 2 == editText.getSelectionStart() && !isClickDot(ch)) {
            int currIndex = stringBuilder.indexOf(".") + 1;
            stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(currIndex + 1);
            editText.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
            editText.setSelection(currIndex + 1);
            count++;
        }

        // replace last digit after decimal
        if (stringBuilder.indexOf(".") + 3 == editText.getSelectionStart() && !isClickDot(ch)) {
            int currIndex = stringBuilder.indexOf(".") + 2;
            stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(currIndex + 1);
            editText.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
            editText.setSelection(currIndex + 1);
            count++;
        }

        // if string builder after decimal have more than 2 length then delete it
        if (editText.getSelectionEnd() == stringBuilder.length() && stringBuilder.subSequence(stringBuilder.indexOf(".") + 1, stringBuilder.length()).length() > digitsAfteZero) {
            stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(editText.getSelectionEnd() - 1);
            editText.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
            editText.setSelection(stringBuilder.length());
        }


        editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
    } else {
        editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);

        if (s.toString().length() == 3 && s.toString().contains(".") && s.toString().substring(0, s.toString().indexOf('.')).length() == 0) {
            // place zero befor decimal
            String zeroBeforeDecimal = "0" + s.toString();
            stringBuilder.setLength(0);
            stringBuilder.append(zeroBeforeDecimal);
            editText.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
            isFirstDigitBeforeDecimalZero = true;
        }

        // if cursor is moved to other side of decimal now move it to left side of decimal
        if (stringBuilder.toString().contains(".") && editText.getSelectionStart() == stringBuilder.indexOf(".")) {
            stringBuilder.setLength(0);
            stringBuilder.append(s);
            stringBuilder.insert(stringBuilder.length() - 2, ".");
            editText.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
            editText.setSelection(stringBuilder.indexOf("."));
        }

        // if cursor is after one digit after decimal
        if (stringBuilder.indexOf(".") + 1 == editText.getSelectionStart()) {
            int currIndex = stringBuilder.indexOf(".") + 1;
            stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(currIndex);
            stringBuilder.insert(currIndex, "0");
            editText.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
            editText.setSelection(currIndex - 1);
        }

        // if cursor is on last digit then replace it with zero
        if (stringBuilder.indexOf(".") + 2 == editText.getSelectionStart()) {
            int currIndex = stringBuilder.indexOf(".") + 2;
            stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(currIndex);
            stringBuilder.insert(currIndex, "0");
            editText.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
            editText.setSelection(currIndex);
        }

        editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
}

boolean isClickDot(char dot) {
    if (dot == '.')
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

}