# EditText for price

Tags: android, android-edittext

I would like to have an EditText like that :
[image]

With the currency (on the left or on the right, it depend of the local currency).

When the user edit the EditText, the "box" have to be only with the decimal (15), and after editing, It would be great to see "$15" or "15€".

I try a lot of way but to do that nothing is working.

Comment: Could you append currency after editting with events when losing focus on EditText?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Better way to Format Currency Input editText?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107901/better-way-to-format-currency-input-edittext)

Comment: On even in `onTextChange` you can achieve this easily

Answer (score 2):

This code works fine!!

```
//metFirstName is a edittext variable name
     metFirstName.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener()     {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (!hasFocus) {
               metFirstName.setText(metFirstName.getText().toString()+"your special char");
                }
             }
    });
```

Comment: Vote this question if you get solution.Thanks in advance :)