# Android Currency - java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "099 "

Tags: android, numberformatexception, currency-formatting

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "099 "

This is the error I'm getting when I run [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5233488/6427630) from another SO answer that formats an EditText into currency (two numbers after comma).

I will repost my code here:

```
price.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    String current = Double.toString(sub.getPrice());

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if(!s.toString().equals("")){
            price.removeTextChangedListener(this);

            String replaceable = String.format("[%s,.]", NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale).getCurrency().getSymbol());

            String cleanString = s.toString().replaceAll(replaceable, "");

            double parsed = Double.parseDouble(cleanString);
            String formatted = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format((parsed/100));

            current = formatted;
            price.setText(formatted);
            price.setSelection(formatted.length());

            price.addTextChangedListener(this);
        }
    }
});
```

`price` is simply an `EditText`.

**What I tried so far:**

I tried forcing the currency to be USD ($) instead of being based on `locale` and the error doesn't show up, While if I use EURO (based on locale) I get the error.

Also what I noticed that switching the currency from USD to EUR the symbol changes from something like `$9,00` to `9,00 €`. I suspect that the space between the numbers and the € causes the `NumberFormatException` but I have no clue on how to fix it.

Comment: Trim your string, if you want it to be a valid numeric string.

Comment: I really don't get why it has been voted down...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NumberFormatException and how can I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849984/what-is-a-numberformatexception-and-how-can-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space in "9,00 €" is indeed causing the problem.

Now you have two options:

- Add the whitespace to the replaceable characters to remove it, i.e. we include `\s`:

  ```
  String replaceable = String.format("[%s,.\\s]", NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale).getCurrency().getSymbol());
  ```
- Or trim the space before trying to parse it as a double:

  ```
  cleanString = cleanString.trim();
  double parsed = Double.parseDouble(cleanString);
  ```

Comment: `[%s,.\\s]` did the trick for me, thanks for the great answer.