# TextInput with typing digits from right to left and adding zeroes automatically for money input

Tags: react-native, textinput

I'm trying to implement `TextInput` with typing digits from right to left and adding zeroes automatically while user is typing. Any ideas how to implement this correctly?

The expected behavior should look like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45094952/implementing-atm-numeric-input-behaviour-in-android-edittext).

[image]

What I have right now:

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      payrate: '',
    };
  }

  handleTextChange = (text) => {
    const newAmount = parseFloat(text/100);
     this.setState({
       payrate: newAmount,
     })


 <TextInput
         autoFocus
         style={[styles.textInput]}
         value={payrate}
         placeholder="0.00"
         maxLength={9}
         keyboardType="numeric"
         placeholderTextColor="#adecf5"
         onChangeText={this.handleTextChange}
         underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
         autoCapitalize="none"
         selection={{start: cursor, end: cursor}}
         />
```

Comment: I have customized the TextInput for USA Number format I think yes, this can be done. Please check my blog. https://medium.com/@maulikdhameliya/how-to-format-number-input-to-usa-phone-number-format-in-react-native-e68363b0c6e4 to make it from right, give textAlign right

Comment: have you solve that problem,?

Answer (score -1):

We use react-native-masked-text for that, works decently. https://github.com/benhurott/react-native-masked-text/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Is it possible to type text from right to left there?

Comment: this does't answer the question regarding typing right to left

Comment: it's been awhile, but I believe the library I shared supports RTL. Also just checked the GH page and looks like the developer isn't supporting it anymore.