# How to change behaviour of EditText to input Currency?

Tags: java, android

I am in need of a currency type EditText and using this currently:
https://github.com/faranjit/currency_edittext

The problem with this is, you have to type decimal fields too.

**Wrong:**

If you want to input **$1** you need to press `1-0-0`.

If you want to type **$1.5** you need to press `1-5-0`.

**However what I want to achieve is:**

If you want to input **$1** , you just press `1`

If you want to input **$1.5**, you press `1-DOT-5`

How should I modify this code to work like this?

Comment: Why don't you use a normal edit text with android:digits="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,." with a dollar sign at the begining?

Comment: I need the formatting it offers, like grouping and limiting decimal digits.

Comment: Those answers here might be helpfull: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107901/better-way-to-format-currency-input-edittext

Comment: I checked it, but it is exact same behaviour I don't want. When I press 2 number it starts with $0.02 instead of 2$.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me Try doing it

```
 editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        private String current = "";

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                  int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (!s.toString().equals(current)) {
                editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);

                Locale local = new Locale("id", "id");
                String replaceable = String.format("[Rp,.\\s]",
                        NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().getCurrency()
                                .getSymbol(local));
                String cleanString = s.toString().replaceAll(replaceable,
                        "");

                double parsed;
                try {
                    parsed = Double.parseDouble(cleanString);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    parsed = 0.00;
                }

                NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat
                        .getCurrencyInstance(local);
                formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
                formatter.setParseIntegerOnly(true);
                String formatted = formatter.format((parsed));

                String replace = String.format("[Rp\\s]",
                        NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().getCurrency()
                                .getSymbol(local));
                String clean = formatted.replaceAll(replace, "");

                current = formatted;
                editText.setText(clean);
                editText.setSelection(clean.length());
                editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I checked it, but it is exact same behaviour I don't want. When I press 2 number it starts with $0.02 instead of 2$.

Comment: I have updated my code please check again is this what you want

Comment: When set text to 123450, this gives to output $1.234,50 instead of $1,234.50.

Comment: You can also try this link https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/5374, i think this is the solution you want

Comment: Thousand seperators are working fine but how do you add decimal part? Pressing dot or comma don't do anything.

Comment: The one you linked is same I used, you can see in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Set input type number.

To do so replace `android:inputType="numberDecimal"` with `android:inputType="number"`.